# CoffeeScript/JavaScript: why assign a letter to a variable that has a number assigned?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm an inexperienced JavaScript user working through the book [CoffeeScript: Accelerated JavaScript Development](http://pragprog.com/book/tbcoffee/coffeescript), in which the author makes a kind of Scrabble app (with Scrabble words in a 5 x 5 grid) to demonstrate some of the concepts in practice.  I'm having a bit of trouble with the `randomLetter` method below. Can someone explain the code snippet below, with reference to these points:

i) the author does `x = 1` but then seems to assign a letter to x with, `x += tileCounts[letter]`.  Why do that?

ii) If, contrary to what I assume in (i), he is assigning a number rather than a letter to x, how does it work that 'letter' actually represents the number associated with each letter?

iii) based on what you see here, can you figure out why he would only return x if it was greater than the randomNumber? I realize there may not be enough information here to answer this question but if there is, please explain

```
tileCounts =
  A: 9, B: 2, C: 2, D: 4, E: 12, F: 2, G: 3, H: 2, I: 9, J: 1, K: 1, L: 4
  M: 2, N: 6, O: 8, P: 2, Q: 1, R: 6, S: 4, T: 6, U: 4, V: 2, W: 2, X: 1
  Y: 2, Z: 1

totalTiles = 0
totalTiles += count for letter, count of tileCounts
alphabet = (letter for letter of tileCounts).sort()

randomLetter = ->  
  randomNumber = Math.ceil Math.random() * totalTiles
  x = 1
  for letter in alphabet
    x += tileCounts[letter]
    return letter if x > randomNumber
#END:moduleVars
```

Comment: If you're new to Javascript I suggest you start with vanilla Javascript and try to understand the basics of the language, like objects, prototypes, call and apply, etc

Comment: thanks, have read a book on the basics, it's just while i'm working through actual code i get it all confused so ask for explanation.

Comment: Have you tried adding a few `console.log` calls so that you can watch the code working and see what the variables contain? I'd suggest using a debugger but I don't know of any CoffeeScript-aware debuggers.

Comment: `tileCounts[letter]` isn't a letter. It's the number corresponding to the letter.

Comment: This question is not particular to javascript. These features (or confusions for you) will be seen in any other scripting language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that `randomLetter()` is difficult to understand. As the author of the book, let me try to clarify.

The only form of randomness available to us in pure JavaScript is `Math.random()`, which returns a number between 0 and 1. So the idea of `randomLetter()` is to convert that random number into a random letter, with each letter having a probability of being drawn that's proportionate to the number of Scrabble tiles with that letter.

To make the analogy of what we're simulating more precise, picture a stack of all the Scrabble tiles sorted from `"A"` to `"Z"`. Then all we have to do is:

1. Convert the output of `Math.random()` (with range `0` to `1`) into something with range `0` to `totalTiles` (the size of the tile stack) and assign it to `randomNumber`.
2. Go through the stack until we get to the `randomNumber`-th tile and return that letter.

In hindsight, I should probably have written this function to more literally follow that analogy by first creating an array of all the tiles and then drawing random values from it. Instead, I opted for an indirect approach: Iterating through the letters of the alphabet, drawing all the tiles with that letter, and asking "Have we drawn `randomNumber` tiles yet? If so, we've reached our random letter."

So to give a short answer: **`x` represents the number of tiles that have been drawn from the stack, starting by drawing all of the `"A"`s, then the `"B"`s, and so on.**

I hope that helps!